# Pinterest sharing with App Pin

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, pinterest

How would I, using the share sheet, share a UIImage on Pinterest and have it link to my app. So that Pinterest users could install my app directly from the Pinterest app?

http://blog.pinterest.com/post/110786995184/install-the-best-new-iphone-and-ipad-apps-from

I can do do manually on my mac. Using the Pinterest browser button I can pin an image, either from my device or from a webpage, and then edit the pin's source to an iTunes page, i.e. https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/snapchat/id447188370?mt=8

... then it will allow me to install Snapchat from within Pinterest app. I'm just not sure how I can do this within my app, with a custom image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing with Pinterest, via the share sheet, only allows you to share an image. If you look closer at the [Pinterest iOS SDK](https://developers.pinterest.com/ios/), you're still limited to sharing the following details:

- Image URL
- Source web page
- Description

When you tell the SDK to pin the image + page, you are taken into the Pinterest app, and the rest is handled there.

The idea you're asking about is a deal between Apple and Pinterest. It seems possible to pin your app's iTunes URL in order to provide this special capability. I haven't seen any details about how this actually works. Is it possible from the share sheet? Maybe - try pinning from the iTunes website.

Comment: thanks, i've worked out how to do it manually. updated my question. but still not sure how to do it with share sheet in iOS app.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that even from some kind of app extension (which would require your app to already be installed). Try looking at SKStoreProductViewController, which you can use to display an app store page in your apps. Otherwise, there isn't much you'll be able to do.

Comment: @cannyboy can you give any more details on how you accomplished this manually?